# C++ vs Haskell: производительность

Tags: c++, haskell, benchmark

Сравниваю производительность. В качестве примера взята [эта задача](http://habrahabr.ru/post/258483/).
Решение на Си++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/rational.hpp>

using namespace boost;

typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_int LL;

const char MSG_ERR[] = "Error\n";
const size_t MSG_ERR_LEN = std::strlen(MSG_ERR);

rational<LL> *x;

rational<LL> fun(const rational<LL> & y, const rational<LL> & z) {
    rational<LL> ret = 108 - (815 - (1500 / z))/y;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argn, char *argv[]) {
    if(argn != 2) {
        std::cout.write(MSG_ERR, MSG_ERR_LEN);
        return 1;
    }
    int n = std::atoi(argv[1]) + 1;
    if(n < 1) {
        std::cout.write(MSG_ERR, MSG_ERR_LEN);
        return 1;
    }
    x = new rational<LL>[n];
    x[0] = 4;
    x[1] = rational<LL>(17,4);
    for(int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
        x[i] = fun(x[i-1], x[i-2]);
    std::cout << x[n-1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Haskell:

```
import Data.Ratio
import System.Environment

f y z = 108 - (815 - 1500 / z) / y

xlist = 4 : (17 % 4) : zipWith f (tail xlist) xlist

main = do
     args <- getArgs
     case args of
                [arg1] -> do
                            let x = read arg1
                            putStrLn $ show $ xlist !! x
                _      -> error "ERR: Main.Args"
```

Результаты:
C++:

```
$ clang++37 -O3 -I/usr/local/include -o CPP t1.cpp 
$ time ./CPP 10000 > /dev/null
       39,64 real        39,62 user         0,00 sys
```

Haskell:

```
$ ghc -O2 t1.hs -o HS
Linking HS ...
$ time ./HS 10000 > /dev/null
        6,73 real         6,73 user         0,00 sys
```

Чем можно объяснить столь существенную разницу? Буст? Лень?

Comment: Ну, вы используете в C++-решении довольно медленный boost::rational, а на Хаскеле пользуетесь нативными типами. Ваш тест несправедлив по отношению к C++, вы измеряете не одно и то же.

Comment: Т.е. в шаблонах буста на скорость не рассчитывать?

Comment: Это да, но всё равно не думаю, что рантайм-сложность операций на `boost::rational<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>` сравнима с рантайм-сложностью `int` (который используется по факту как несущий тип в Хаскелевском коде).

Comment: Кстати, я сравнивал и с boost::multiprecision::cpp_rational. Этот вариант ещё медленнее.

Comment: @Nex: Ну тк. Вы сравниваете две числомолотилки, тут всё упирается в скорость операций. Хаскель наверняка может на таком простом коде обеспечить оптимальную или почти оптимальную кодогенерацию.

Comment: А профайлер натравить пробовали для поиска узких мест?

Comment: Объяснить можно тем, что у GHC офигенный оптимизатор стал. Тормоз легко может оказаться на выводной печати. Вобщем профилировать нужно.

Comment: А в Хаскеле тип-то Integer вывелся?

Answer (score 11):

Столь существенную разницу можно объяснить тем что `boost` не максимально оптимизирован, хотя результат намного лучше чем писать длинную арифметику вручную.

Теперь рассмотрим какой потенциал мы можем выжать из `С++`. Для этого будем использовать библиотеку `GMP`, возьмём этот код:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <gmpxx.h>

const char MSG_ERR[] = "Error\n";
const size_t MSG_ERR_LEN = std::strlen(MSG_ERR);

mpq_class fun(const mpq_class & y, const mpq_class & z) {
    mpq_class ret = 108 - (815 - (1500 / z))/y;
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout.write(MSG_ERR, MSG_ERR_LEN);
        return 1;
    }

    int n = std::atoi(argv[1]) + 1;

    if(n < 1)
    {
        std::cout.write(MSG_ERR, MSG_ERR_LEN);
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<mpq_class> v;
    v.push_back(mpq_class(4, 1));
    v.push_back(mpq_class(17, 4));

    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(fun(v[i - 1], v[i - 2]));
    }
    std::cout << v.rbegin()->get_num() << " / " << v.rbegin()->get_den() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И соберём все результаты в кучу, на своей машине я получил такой результат:

Haskell

```
> ghc -O2 test.hs -o HS
> time ./HS 10000 > /dev/null 
real    0m7.491s
user    0m7.420s
sys     0m0.004s
```

C++, boost

```
> g++-5 -O2 -o CPP test.cpp
> time ./CPP 10000 > /dev/null
real    0m22.272s
user    0m22.256s
sys     0m0.012s

> clang++ -O2 -o CPP-CLANG test.cpp
> time ./CPP-CLANG 10000 > /dev/null
real    0m20.638s
user    0m20.628s
sys     0m0.008s
```

C++, gmp

```
> g++-5 -O2 -std=c++14 -lgmpxx -lgmp -o CPP-GMP testgmp.cpp
> time ./CPP-GMP 10000 > /dev/null
real    0m1.418s
user    0m1.404s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Мы убедились, что `boost` не даёт нам максимальную производительность.